# Breaking JavaFX when Tab character is pasted into TextField

Tags: java, exception, javafx, textfield

The JavaFX Application Thread throws a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` if the user pastes a tab character into a `TextField`. How can I smartly prevent a user from breaking my application in this way?

Here's a minimal example that demonstrates the behavior.

```
//Defined in Main.java
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader
                    .load(getClass().getResource("MainView.fxml"));
            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Defined in MainView.fxml:

```
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
        <TextField fx:id="tf" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**Procedure:**

1. Copy a tab character (`\t`) to the clipboard
2. Type something into the `TextField`
3. Highlight the text in the `TextField`
4. Paste the contents of the clipboard to replace the highlighted text

The exception occurs whether the user uses the keyboard shortcut (Ctrl+V in Windows) or the context menu. I certainly could add a try-catch block to every `TextField`, but that would clutter up the code, and how do I know that this exception is only thrown in this one situation?

*Note:* This is issue does not appear to affect `TextArea`

**Full text of the exception:**

```html
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.substring(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.substring(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.control.TextField$TextFieldContent.get(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.getText(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.updateContent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.replaceText(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.replaceText(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.replaceSelection(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.paste(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.paste(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.callAction(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase.callActionForEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.callActionForEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase.lambda$new$74(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$1800(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent$353(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: the code you posted is not helping us at all, we need to see the code where you are manipulating the StringBuilder

Comment: @Xoce웃Пepeúpa I don't manipulate the `StringBuilder`; it's internal to the `TextField` implementation. The code I posted is a *full* minimal example that can reproduce the results.

Comment: you are right. I just tried it at my own application. I've got the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that's ugly. You should report this as a bug.

You can workaround this with a `TextFormatter` which filters out tab (and newline) characters. You might want to replace the tab character with, e.g. four spaces.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter.Change;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TextFieldBug extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField tf = new TextField();
        tf.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<String>((Change c) -> {
            String text = c.getText();
            int oldAnchor = c.getAnchor();
            int oldCaretPos = c.getCaretPosition() ;
            int initialLength = text.length();
            text = text.replaceAll("\t", "    ");
            text = text.replaceAll("\n", "");
            c.setText(text);
            c.setAnchor(oldAnchor + text.length() - initialLength);
            c.setCaretPosition(oldCaretPos + text.length() - initialLength);
            return c ;
        }));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(tf), 350, 120));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug. As a workaround, you could handle the error in the `DefaultUncaughtEcxeptionHanlder` such that the application doesn't crash (see e..g. [General Exception handling in JavaFX 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26361559/general-exception-handling-in-javafx-8))

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem with the `javafx.scene.control.TextField`, so I reported it as a bug: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8212102 / https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8212102. The Oracle people say that this is a regression in JDK 8u40. As long as it's not fixed the workaround James_D suggested works like a charm.