# Java(FX) Fail-Safe Alert on Faulty Termination / Crash?

Tags: java, javafx, shutdown-hook

I absolutely need my programme to exit cleanly, i.e. if and only if the user does it manually. In any other case, my programme must notify them either by means of displaying a popup or, better yet, playing a sound (on loop).

Hence: is there a fool-proof, fail-safe way for me to alert the user that something has gone wrong? Even if the exception already occurrs in JavaFX's `Application#start` method? I was experimenting with shutdown hooks, but the general consensus here on SO is that they are not meant for such heavy operations.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26361559/general-exception-handling-in-javafx-8

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is surround parts of your program with `try catch` statements. That way when an error occurs you can create a pop-up in the catch statement. The other solution is the throws exception however that will not allow you to create a pop up notifying the user upon an error.

Comment: thx for the idea but i am already making extensive use of `try - catches` in all critical parts of my code. I even threw in a few `finally`s^^ However and especially with regard to performance / overhead, I can't simply do something like `public void start (Stage primaryStage) { try { runProgramme(); } catch (Exception e) { displayPopup(e); } }`. There are a ton of things that may happen outside of the JavaFX thread and potentially kill my application.