# Array Index Out Of Bounds Exception without any further information. No line number, no class, just the exception

Tags: javafx, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

Lots of answers around this exception, but genuinely, I understand the reason and how to fix, but can't find the root cause, so please read before assuming it's a duplicate. Thanks in advance.

As the documentation says:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html

An ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is "*Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array.*"

That's fairly self explanatory, however, I am getting this exception, without any further information. No class name, no line number, just the exception.

`Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

[image: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException]

This just loops and loops until I kill the program.

I am more than happy to start trying to show bits of code to give a fully verifiable example etc. However...

### My question at this stage is:

Is there any way I can ensure than all my exception are printed out into the output with the respective line numbers?

Some things I have already tried:

- Try catches around the suspect loops and array assignments etc. to no avail.
- Attempted to set up Error Handling across the app (using the accepted answer in here: [General Exception handling in JavaFX 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26361559/general-exception-handling-in-javafx-8)), but when I replicated the error, I got even less information.

### Further information about issue:

- The array is created based of a PDF document. The number of pages in this document are counted, and the array is given the number of pages as it's length.  Then, each page is set, using it's page number - 1 (which starts from 0, and for example, goes up to 200 when there are 201 pages.
- This array is then used to display the same number of panels as there are pages within a tab, in a scrollpane. Once they are created, this functionality never runs again.
- This all works fine, initially.
- When scrolling up and down, the panels have a buffered image of the page added to it's label graphic.  This all works fine, scroll up, scrolling down, dragging the thumb etc.
- However, when zooming in and out (basically resizing the panels created by each array element), after several (over 15/20) times of clicking the buttons to do this, which fire off the same functionality as when scrolling up and down after resizing the panels, eventually I get this exception.
- So, initially, it's all working, all the array has been created, it has a specific number of elements, I can see that it is working when scrolling up and down, I can see that the number of pages and number of loops through the components in a foreach (eg. `for(Node n: parentNode.getChildrenUnmodifiable()){}`) are the same / as expected.
- In this loop, I am specifically getting elements from the array using the page number - 1 as it was created.  This never goes above the length of the array and never equals -1 (as it starts from 1, so first iteration is 0).
- Before the arrays are used, or assigned too.. I check that:

`if ((array.length > 0) && (array.length == numberOfPagesInDocument) && (counter < numberOfPagesInDocument)) {}`

- This ensures that the array has elements, and that the length is the same number of pages as in the document as the array size shoudl always be the same as the number of pages in the document, and obviously, works until I have spammed the zoom in or out buttons many times.
- This is the only Array that is in use in the app at this point, others have already been created, used and there functionallity is not ran at this time, but I'm struggling to see how this can be causing the error.
- A small part of me feels like, as it on sperate threads when calling zoom in etc or scrolling etc. that too many threads are muddying the pot, but that's just an assumption from me grasping at straws a little bit.

Any help would be appreciated and thank you in advance, and if everyone is at a loss, I will work at being able to provide further information and examples of the code.

### Edit:

The issue I am having is with:

`Bounds childBounds = child.localToScene(child.getBoundsInLocal());`

```
The task failed with the following exception:
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:422)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:435)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.get(ObservableListWrapper.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.get(VetoableListDecorator.java:306)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.updateCachedBounds(Parent.java:1591)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1535)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1388)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3577)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3530)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3478)
    at javafx.scene.Node$MiscProperties$2.computeBounds(Node.java:6472)
    at javafx.scene.Node$LazyBoundsProperty.get(Node.java:9306)
    at javafx.scene.Node$LazyBoundsProperty.get(Node.java:9276)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getBoundsInLocal(Node.java:3156)
    at tdiesfxml.Utility$3.call(Utility.java:252)
    at tdiesfxml.Utility$3.call(Utility.java:235)
    at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1423)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

These are `Bounds` though, so a little perplexed as to why this is throwing the Exception that I am getting.

I am now researching this issue, not sure what to do with this questions as it's evolved a bit, but I will add my findings here, and if anyone has an idea why Bounds throw this Exception I would be greatly appreciative.

Comment: It's commercial.. so bit of a grey area.

Comment: Certainly will do if no-one can help me with my actual question regarding exception handling though. Just means I need to think about what I'm sharing =]

Comment: Just using the basic `array.get(counter)`, and but the elements are already all in the array, so it's highly puzzling.

Comment: Just need to try and get more information on the exception itself, and then I can fix it, but how to find where this is being caused, when the only array in use seems to be okay is where I am struggling as I always get more information with exception, just not with this one!

Comment: I would step through the code using the debugger in NetBeans, however, it only happens at random after firing the same functionality with the zoom buttons many times, so stepping through to replicate could well be a massive, time consuming nightmare, so a line number with the exception, or even a class, would be delightful!

Comment: @Dammeul If (as printed) exception originates from JavaFx thread you should be able to catch it in application start() method. Have you tried that?

Comment: Ahh, I haven't but that is what I will try now, thanks... fingers cross..!

Comment: I did try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26361559/general-exception-handling-in-javafx-8 with no joy, but will look at some other solutions that are more basic than that one.

Comment: @Dammeul Let me know about the result.

Comment: Thanks @PrzemekKrysztofiak, I didn't resolve this using start() exactly, but from following your suggestion, I realised that I could capture the Threads setOnFailed() event, and a bit of playing about made me realise that other Stack Traces were being suppressed, so `System.err.println(Arrays.toString(uploadingFileTask.getException().getSuppressed()));` within setOnFailed() produced a proper Stack Trace...

Comment: Which showed me my issue is not what I was expecting: `Bounds childBounds = child.localToScene(child.getBoundsInLocal());` ... I use that to detect whether the panels are within the Scroll Panes viewable area, but spamming zoom in and out kills it for some reason... so more investigating to do, but on the right track (hopefully) now.

Comment: Based on that stack trace the problem is caused by you modifying/accessing the GUI on a background thread.

Comment: @Slaw, I think I might love you. Can't seem to replicate the issue now I've removed it from a Task and places try / catches where needed.  Hopefully, I'm not jumping the gun, but it feels like it's working for me.  

I did initially have issues with not running it on a background thread as the panels had to be created first and were part of the same method (I'm rewriting an already existing application), but I changed that to be separate the other day.

Comment: PrzemekKrysztofiak and @Slaw, thank you so much for your help guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on that stack trace, the problem is you're accessing and/or modifying the GUI from a background thread.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:422)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:435)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.get(ObservableListWrapper.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.get(VetoableListDecorator.java:306)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.updateCachedBounds(Parent.java:1591)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1535)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1388)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3577)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3530)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3478)
    at javafx.scene.Node$MiscProperties$2.computeBounds(Node.java:6472)
    at javafx.scene.Node$LazyBoundsProperty.get(Node.java:9306)
    at javafx.scene.Node$LazyBoundsProperty.get(Node.java:9276)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getBoundsInLocal(Node.java:3156)
    at tdiesfxml.Utility$3.call(Utility.java:252)               // HERE
    at tdiesfxml.Utility$3.call(Utility.java:235)               // HERE
    at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1423) // HERE
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) // HERE
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The lines marked with `// HERE` indicate the code is an implementation of `javafx.concurrent.Task`. Inside the `call` method of this `Task` you call `Node.getBoundsLocal` which shows you accessing the GUI from a class primarily meant for background execution.

JavaFX, like most UI toolkits, is single-threaded. You must never interact with a live scene-graph on a background thread; you must be on the *JavaFX Application Thread*. If you need information from the UI while on a background thread you can use `Platform.runLater` with something like `CompletableFuture` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50067565/how-to-properly-thread-off-javafx-alerts-filechooser-etc)).

Answer (score 0):

You Can Add Your Code To which The Node is Being Updated
Into platform runlater which will be run on the **JavaFX Thread**.

```
 Platform.runLater(()->{
                  //put the code here
               
                    });
```